# Alarm management in Icinga?

Tags: nagios, icinga

Can Icinga be used as an alarm management tool?

The docs are very clear about two types of monitoring:

- Host/Service Health (system is up, down, flapping, etc)
- Host/Service Performance Data (key-value pairs supplied by plugin, reporting w/ charts)

I think I'm looking for a third type of monitoring:  is there any built-in functionality that would handle asynchronous software alarms that don't necessarily disrupt a service but need to be logged / managed?

For example,  say a key process on a server cores but restarts itself.  The service is running, but I'd like to be able to see that a core event happened (preferably with some kind of severity).

Any built-in feature that would do this for me?  Any plugins that would add this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Log monitoring and alerting on the events you specify. There are tons of options out there to do this kind of stuff.

One such option is passive checks combined with snmp traps. A script parses your application log and sends the trap that then displays in nagios.